# Не работает header() в isset($_POST['submit'])

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с проблемой, но не совсем понимаю почему так происходит и как обойти.

На странице находится 2 формы, в каждой форме по 2 поля и по 1 кнопке.

```
<form action="" name="frm1" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fn" id="fn"/>
  <input type="text" name="ln" id="ln"/>
  <input type="submit" name='submitlogin1'/>
</form>
```

и

```
<form action="" name="frm2" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fn" id="fn"/>
  <input type="text" name="ln" id="ln"/>
  <input type="submit" name='submitlogin2'/>
</form>
```

Далее прописан обработчик:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitlogin1'])){
  $name = $_POST["fn"];
  header("Location: /list.php?name=$name");
}
```

и

```
if(isset($_POST['submitlogin2'])){
  $name = $_POST["ln"];
  header("Location: /list.php?name=$name");
}
```

Условия обрабатываются - но переадресация не происходит.

Если я уберу со страницы 1 форму и оставлю 1 обработчик, все работает, переадресация происходит.

Почему оно не хочет работать с двумя формами и как это обойти? Спасибо!

Comment: А после `header("Location:...` еще и `exit();` делать надо.

Comment: @Visman да, но увы, это не заставит код работать (проверил)

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что один из этих обработчиков *PHP* расположен после *HTML* кода и в итоге `header` не сработает, а всё потому, что

> Помните, что функцию **header()** можно вызывать только если клиенту еще не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML тэгов, пустых строк и т.п. Довольно часто возникает ошибка, когда при чтении кода файловыми функциями, вроде include или require, в этом коде попадаются пробелы или пустые строки, которые выводятся до вызова **header()**. Те же проблемы могут возникать и при использовании одиночного PHP/HTML файла.

```
<html>
<?php
/* Этот пример приведет к ошибке. Обратите внимание
 * на тэг вверху, который будет выведен до вызова header() */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```

цитата из документации: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

---

так что код должен быть в самом верху

Comment: Не соглашусь. Когда на странице одна форма, то не важно сколько текста перед header(), он все равно отработает в конце и передаст $_GET запрос

Comment: @ВладимирВ. серьезно? ну вам надо нобеля дать за то, что сломали систему

Comment: Было бы неплохо, но проблема не в этом. Я убрал все перед header, но переадресация все равно не происходит

Comment: @ВладимирВ. ок. давайте так. 1) в самом начале файла напишите `<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` и посмотрите какие ошибки выдает.. 2) покажите **полностью** всю страницу как она сейчас есть со всем убранным лишним мусором перед `header` (в вопрос добавьте например) 3) страница должна быть в кодировке utf-8 без BOM